# TFS 2013, added project to wrong solution under team project collection

Tags: tfs

I just discovered that I somehow managed to add a project to the wrong solution in my team project collection.  I have a team project collection named DotNetWindowsProjects.  Under that I have two solutions; AccountManager and SafetySuggestions.  Each solution is supposed to have one project under it.

The AccountManager solution should have the AccountManager project under it and SafetySuggestions is supposed to have the SafetySuggestions project under it.  Both projects are under the AccountManager solution and the SafetySuggestions solution is empty.  How do I get the SafetySuggestions project moved to the SafetySuggestions solution without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1):

I would 1st back up both solutions locally.

then open safety solution in vs.  then add the safety project to it.

check that in.

then open account solution in vs and delete the safety project.

check that in.

Get latest in a fresh location and check to see that all is well.  (note make sure to test in vs post move that everything builds etc. as it might look good in tfs but not actually work)